# How can I detect iPad with modernizr for custom css

Tags: ipad, css, modernizr

I have strange web layout view on iPad but at user web browser its fine. I want use modernizr as detection on custom css that i want made only for iPad.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS ANSWER ISN'T VALID ANYMORE.

Modernizr has changed since I answered this question...

====================

Modernizr adds a bunch of CSS selectors to the HTML tag.

If you are using iPad, it adds the selector "os-iPad".

Therefore you can target iPad related CSS prefixing them with: `html.os-iPad`

```
html.os-iPad body
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure Modernizr adds this by default??

Comment: Yes, Inspect the element in Chrome the element HTML. You will see that there is at least 20 css classes in there.

Comment: Modernizr does not (anymore ?) add this class. You can use Detectizr, a Modernizr extension, to add such behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

This question is 1year old, but i stumbled across the same problem : detecting an ipad with Modernizr…

I've never seen that Modernizr adds os-ipad class… Actually to detect an iPad you have to set up custom tests, like this one for example :

```
Modernizr.addTest('ipad', function () {
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
});
```

So, i'm quite surprised to see that the previous answer was accepted as the best answer… Or maybe that option was removed from current Modernizr build ?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an older thread - and probably already been covered in other places.  However, I still managed to get here and didn't get a good answer for my needs.

What I ended up finding to work for most of my general needs is the Modernizr html class "touch".  For instance on desktop, I use some "fixed" background images.  Mobile devices don't like that too well, so...

in scss:

```
html.touch {
   .element {
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

I realize this doesn't exactly answer the OP's question targeting iPad specifically, but this will most likely help at least some people with similar issues to mine.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use css media queries for that. Have a look at the less framework located here: 
http://lessframework.com/